# include(MultiModelForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

```
 <?php
if(!isset($data)) {$data=array(); };
    $this->widget('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm',array(
        'id' => 'id_ssc_affliations', //the unique widget id
        'formConfig' => $myFormConfig, //the form configuration array
        'model' => $model, //instance of the form model
        'tableView'=>true,
        'data'=>$data,
        'bootstrapLayout'=>true,
        'addItemAsButton'=>true,
        'jsAfterNewId'=>MultiModelForm::afterNewIdDateTimePicker($myFormConfig['elements']),

        //if submitted not empty from the controller,
        //the form will be rendered with validation errors
        //'validatedItems' => $validatedMembers,

        //array of member instances loaded from db
        //'data' => $member->findAll('groupid=:groupId', array(':groupId'=>$model->id)),
    ));
?>
```

I'm getting this error please help me

Error 500
include(MultiModelForm.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: check your file permissions

Comment: Yeah.. I already gave. it works perfectly.but when I want to add DatePIcker in multimodel form this error is occurred...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
Yii::import('ext.multimodelform.MultiModelForm');
```

at the top of this file.

I assume `$this->widget()` implicitly imports the `MultiModelForm` class too.

The problem is that you pass `MultiModelForm::afterNewIdDateTimePicker($myFormConfig['elements'])` as an argument to it. So your app should know the class `MultiModelForm` in advance before calling the `widget()` function. Adding explicit `import` at the top should solve this problem.

Comment: error gone. but new problem came :(  .......

Add Item not working.only one row is adding

Comment: For new error please ask a new question, don't edit this one. And please mark this answer as "accepted" if it helped. Thanks